# Will not install

Tags: install

system freezes while trying to create ext4 on the / partition.  It says it is preparing the drive and then sits there indefinitely.

HISTORY OF THE TROUBLE
on first install attempt, could not mount vfat volume on uefi partition.  My bios is set to legacy boot.  So I erased the partition it had set up as uefi.  Same problem.  When I chose either option of "go back" or "continue" it simply sits there.

Then I tried simply letting it do the work by choosing the option to install it along side my LinuxMint distro.  It got past the uefi error but would start to format my / partition and hang there.  I gave it an hour and still was sitting there with no progress.

I have a ROG STRIX B450 motherboard with an AMD Ryzen 5 3600 cpu.  1.5 TB disk space and 16gb ram.